# Using Python to upload an image to Drupal

Tags: python-3.x, api, drupal

Via the JSON:API I'm creating and updating content entities on Drupal 9.5.8 - for content, taxonomies, relationships it's working fine.

But I can't get images to upload - they seem to be corrupted.
I've tried this sort of script: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3079384#comment-13250753

```
import requests
import os

from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth


def upload_image(image_path):
    api_url = 'https://example.com/jsonapi/node/event/a8ef729b-1fd6-4233-979a-fa0f81132dde/field_image' #?_format=json
    auth = HTTPBasicAuth('Username', 'Password')
    image_filename = os.path.basename(image_path)
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
    'Content-Disposition': 'file; filename="{}"'.format(image_filename.replace('images/', ''))}
    multipart_form_data = {'file': (image_filename, open(image_path, 'rb'))}

    print(api_url)
    print(auth)
    print(image_filename)
    print(headers)
    
    response = requests.post(api_url, files=multipart_form_data, headers=headers, auth=auth)
    
    print(response.json())
    return None
    

upload_image('images/test.jpg')
```

And I've tried and errored with a few other / similar approaches like:

```
def upload_image2(image_path):
    api_url = 'https://example.com/jsonapi/node/event/a8ef729b-1fd6-4233-979a-fa0f81132dde/field_image' #?_format=json
    auth = HTTPBasicAuth('Username', 'Password')
    image_filename = os.path.basename(image_path)
    headers = {'Accept': 'application/vnd.api+json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
            'Content-Disposition': f'file; filename="{image_filename}"'
        }
    with open('images/test.jpg', 'rb') as f:
        response = requests.post(api_url, headers=headers, auth=auth, files={'test.jpg': f})
        
        print(response.json())

    return None
```

Strange enough: Adding `#?_format=json` to the *upload_image2* doesn't change anything. But adding it to *upload_image*, I receive an error:

> {'message': 'No route found for the specified format json. Supported formats: api_json.'}

The image that I'm uploading is 11.1 kB (just trying to upload this screenshot)
[image]

What I see on the website / edit form seems to be broken:
[image]

The uploaded image is 11.3 kB - which I can't upload here, since it's a broken image, as it seems.

According to [that comment](https://www.drupal.org/node/3024331#comment-13318986), I'm not trying to base64 encode the image.

There is a [CURL and Node.js example](https://www.drupal.org/docs/core-modules-and-themes/core-modules/jsonapi-module/file-uploads) - but I wasn't able to transfer it to Python, as it seems.

And in [this ticket](https://www.drupal.org/node/3024331#comment-13318986), it seems as if BasicAuth can be used as well to upload files, so that might not be the issue as well.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much fiddling around, I was able to get it working via this Code: https://www.drupal.org/node/3024331#comment-13248319

It seems like

```
data = bytearray(data)
```

was the missing piece.

Answer (score 0):

For file Uploading review this Drupal.org [Post](https://www.drupal.org/node/2941420#comment-14645161)
which can be done through Postman.

The uploaded image is temporary, you need to reference it somewhere to make it permanent.